# Passing a function as argument to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there any way to send functions as parameters to stored procedures?

```
create procedure stp_dummy 
@input nvarchar(255)
as select @input

exec stp_dummy a_function_that_returns_string('abracadabra')
```

(Of course that I know that the function can be called previously but I would like to know if the direct solution is available.)

Comment: +1, interesting question, I started looking down the path of F# and CLR stored procedures to see if it is even remotely possible.  It is not though.

Comment: [Vote up this request](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but the only way to do this is to declare a local variable, assign the function value to this, and use this as your parameter value:

```
DECLARE @input nvarchar(255)
SET @input = a_function_that_returns_string('abracadabra')
EXEC stp_dummy @input=@input
```

With SQL Server 2008, this can be done in 2 lines:

```
DECLARE @input nvarchar(255) = a_function_that_returns_string('abracadabra')
EXEC stp_dummy @input=@input
```

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei - Yeah I think this is the only way. This also goes for simple things like: `exec sp @string='a'+'b'`. I'm pretty sure that would throw an error.

Comment: @Corovei: Curt is correct.  Unless you want to have a finite number of functions and send a VARCHAR to do a CASE - blah.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a limitation of SQL Server.  You'll have to do something like what Curt demonstrated.